# Black screen after booting Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04, amd-graphics

I am lost as to how to solve my issue after installing Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS yesterday. The ISO SHA was verified and matched. I made sure the MB was Fast boot disabled / secure boot disabled / Legacy boot / no UEFI. I installed ubuntu selecting the erase disk from the live Ubuntu from an USB, everything went well.

Now, when I start my PC, after booting Ubuntu, the screen turns black, the HDMI signal stops. Having found this thread: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

...I realized I should try to run Ubuntu with the `nomodeset` to see if its a GPU driver issue. The problem is, when I press `Right shift` nothing happens. After some googling,some people said to press the `Esc` key instead. Doing this opens a grub command line, so I can't select anything with the keys to edit anything. I cannot figure out how to try `nomodeset`. Where should I go from here?

Hardware:

- MB: ASRock x470 Taichi
- CPU: Ryzen 7 2700x
- GPU: Radeon R9 390x

Update: after @ChanganAuto suggestion I re-enabled UEFI and did a fresh install. As before, I had to install from safe mode because I would get a black screen otherwise. Then, after the first boot, I still get the black screen/no HDMI signal. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: "Legacy boot" is likely where the problem starts. Why do you think you need an option that was last used for Windows XP. For more than a decade PCs come with UEFI so installing in UEFI mode should be preferred for any OS that supports this mode (Ubuntu supporst UEFI mode since 2012!!)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will re-install and post an update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: No, I was trying to follow the instructions (linked in my question) but I cannot enter this grub menu with `Right shift`, only `Esc` opens a grub console, and I can't figure out how to enter a `nomodeset` from there.